# NumPy C extension with SWIG unknown length array

Tags: python, c, numpy, swig

I would like to wrap a C function with SWIG.
The function takes a couple arrays (of the same length) as input and returns three more arrays.
It is however not possible to predict the length of the return arrays beforehand and these are dynamically allocated in the function.
Is it possible to wrap such a function with SWIG (using numpy.i) and if so how?
A simplified function declaration looks like:

```
int func(double **a, double **b, long int *N, double *x, double *y, long int *Nx, long int *Ny);
```

Where `Nx` and `Ny` are known beforehand but `N` (the length of `a` and `b`) is not and `a` and `b` are allocated (with `malloc`) in the function.

Comment: Is this exclusively a C question? Swig makes it a lot easier to solve with `std::vector` from C++, even if you ended up wrapping your original function.

Comment: Yes it is exclusively a C question. I have given up on SWIG for this problem and have written the wrapper manually which works fine. I could post the answer but it is not really an answer to this question since I don't use SWIG.

Comment: No reason to abandon SWIG because of that. Just don't use SWIG's typemaps (they are complex as hell). You can write your own wrappers where required, returning and receiving PyObject* parameters. SWIG will recognize those, while still handling easy cases (like int).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that SWIG (or any other Python wrapper generator for that matter) cannot do this.
I ended up writing the Python wrapper by hand, which is actually quite easy, using `PyArray_SimpleNew` or `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData` to create the output arrays.
With the latter one has to be extra careful so as to not generate memory leaks.
After playing with it a bit I found the former combined with a simple `memcpy` to be safer.